# A program that checks for Palindromness

Tags: java, beginner, palindrome

**Yes, I made it up.**

This program checks if an entered `string` is a palindrome or not by assigning a `char` variable the characters in the inserted word in reverse order. The program then takes the variable and appends it to a  `StringBuilder` to be able to compare the original word and the finalized reversed version.

```
package Palindrome;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class palindrome {

static String word;
StringBuilder reversedWord = new StringBuilder();

public palindrome() {
    char reversedChar;

    for (int i = 1; i < word.length() + 1; i++) {
        reversedChar = word.charAt(word.length() - i);
        reversedWord.append(reversedChar);
    }
}

public void checkPalindrome() {
    if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(reversedWord.toString())) {
        System.out.println("You got a Palindrome!");
    }else{
        System.out.println("That's not a Palindrome...");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter a word to check Palindromness: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    word = scan.next();
    scan.close();
    new palindrome();
    new palindrome().checkPalindrome();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

#### notes:

1. Your coding style seems good. There is some inconsistent indentation,
   but i am guessing that is a question formatting problem.
2. Having a static variable `word` means that `palindrome` is not 
   threadsafe, and is confusing to call. either pass `word` to the
   palindrome constructor, or make `checkPalindrome()` a static method
   that takes a string.
3. `checkPalindrome()` outputs it's result to standard output. What if
   you wanted to make your palindrome checker graphical?. have
   `checkPalindrome()` return a `boolean` indicating whether word is a
   palindrome or not. This concept of seperating model and output code
   is *extremly* important.
4. Instead of wasting time and memory copy over the string backwards then
   checking for equality, you can compare pairs of characters starting at
   both ends of the string.
5. When you reverse the string, you can write a for loop that goes
   backwards:

   ```
   for (int i = word.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
       reversedChar = word.charAt(i);
       reversedWord.append(reversedChar);
   }
   ```

#### example:

```
public boolean checkPalindrome(String word) {
    for (int i = 0; i < word.length() / 2; ++i) {
        if (Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(i)) !=
                Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(word.length()-i-1))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```